Deactivate Duplicate Rules in 2GP Package Version Creation
We are having trouble creating a 2GP package version with code coverage. The unit tests in our package rely on standard Duplicate Rules being deactivated. For context, in our current CI Build, we follow this process:

Create a Scratch Org
Deploy Metadata that deactivates Duplicate Rules
Run the Unit Tests

However, when creating a 2GP package version, unit tests are run in a scratch org with Duplicate Rules activated. I have tried to specify the metadata to deactivate Duplicate Rules as unpackagedMetadata in the sfdx-project.json, as documented here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm
Yet, the duplicate rules are still active and cause our unit tests to fail. I see this was a known issue at one point:
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwRrAAK/cannot-deactivate-standard-duplicate-rule-during-2gp-package-version-create
Is this still a known issue or has there been a resolution? Are there any workarounds for this process?
